# Translate custom validator message

Tags: symfony

**I'm trying to translate a custom constraint message:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class YoutubeLink extends Constraint
{
    public $message = '"{{ string }}" is not a valid Youtube link';

    /**
     * @var TranslatorInterface
     */
    private $translator;

    public function __construct($translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }
}
```

**I'm injecting the translator:**

```
services:
    App\Validator\Constraints\YoutubeLink:
        arguments: [ "@translator" ]
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: validator.youtube_link }
```

**But how to translate the message now with the argument?**

Comment: Validation message are translated in twig rendering after validation process by default. If you need print message in another place, maybe you must do it in controller or service.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the translation key in the entity since `$message` is public:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @AppAssert\YoutubeLink(
 *     message = "link.invalid_youtube"
 * )
 */
protected $url;
```